# Send data to Azure Functions using QueueTrigger from a Nuget package

Tags: azure-functions, nuget-package, azure-storage-account, queuetrigger

I have been testing my Azure Functions using a `QueueTrigger`. I tested my queue by using the following code to put something on the queue.

```cs
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storage.....etc");
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("mysecondqueue");
queue.CreateIfNotExists();
queue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage($"Test {DateTime.Now}"));
```

This works fine, however what I need to do is put this code in a Nuget package. What bothers me is that I have to put the `ConnectionString` of my StorageAccount hard coded in that Nuget package. And this package will be used by 3rd party applications.

I could use an Azure Function with an `HttpTrigger`, but that kind of defeats the purpose of using a Queue.

What would be the best way to put something on a Queue from a Nuget package using a `QueueTrigger`, without exposing the `ConnectionString` of my Storage Account?

Or is my only option using a `HttpTrigger` in this case?

Comment: How the nuget package and Azure function is related w.r.t the mentioned code?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Not sure what you mean. But what happens is that our Nuget package send some sort of telemetry data to our Azure Function. So basically we collect logging information. Right now the Azure Function is a `QueueTrigger`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: So as I understand the flow, Nuget package -> Queue -> Queue Trigger -> Azure function -> further processing pipeline. So your nuget sits in 3rd party system, collects telemetry data and sends to queue. And the issue here is to how to avoid storing queue connection string inside nuget?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Yes, that's correct

Comment: So I guess you are using queue for load-levelling purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can check below 2 approaches,

1. If you are using queue for load levelling purpose and do not want to expose your storage connection string then you can add another azure function which will just connect Nuget to Queue by http trigger and wrap storage connection string
   Nuget -> function (http trigger) -> Queue > function (queue trigger) -> ....

or

2. You can use Azure key vault and store the storage connection string in key vault and access the connection string from nuget via service principle or any standard method